# Is there a Linux equivalent to Windows' SysPrep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat-enterprise-linux, sysprep, fog

Coming into a large number of old PCs that I want to be able to wipe the drives and reload with a "Factory" install of Linux on the HDD.

These machines have no CD-ROMs, so I am looking for something similar to a SysPrep in Windows, and then use [FOG](http://fogproject.org) to capture the image and redistribute.

Anyone know the preferred method to take an existing system and clone it but have it boot up as if it were a brand new install?  IE - ask for username, password, etc.

Specifically, is there a process for RHEL\CentOS & Ubuntu? Procedures for [Open]SuSE and other distros would be nice, but these are the two (three) most pertinent to my current situation.

Comment: Depends on the distro.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - please see edit\update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Ubuntu this looks like it could do what you want

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/virt-sysprep.1.html

Haven't tried it myself but the descriptions fit your request

> "Reset or unconfigure a virtual machine so clones can be made"

Comment: This works for RedHat / CentOS https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-Guest_virtual_machine_disk_access_with_offline_tools-Using_virt_sysprep.html

Answer (score 4):

For RHEL / Fedora, you probably want to look at PXE booting and using kickstart to install. Using a "golden image" (i.e. doing what SysPrep does) isn't really the best way of deploying new machines on RHEL / Fedora (in my opinion). It (Kickstart) lets you distribute identical images without having to take up the space for that image - and lets you update new machines by simply editing the kickstart file/template instead of having to update the golden image, then re-prep it,then re-verify it. I'm told Ubuntu has a "pre-seed" functionality that is substantially similar, but I'm not familiar with it so I can't say anything more than "I know the name".

Comment: I agree the kickstart method is better - just like unattend.xml is better on Windows: so far the closest I've seen is VMware's cloning and Custom Specifications

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Spacewalk:
http://spacewalk.redhat.com/

It is to satellite as fedora is to red hat.

Overview:
Satellite/Spacewalk always you to configure an image for installation over the network.

I am not familiar with FOG or Windows but if you are looking to have a master image and install that on multiple machines over the network you should check out Spacewalk.