# Can I configure an OpenSUSE VM application then trigger the OOBE?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, opensuse

I'd like to be able to configure (e.g. install applications, provision files, perhaps configure some settings for) an OpenSUSE virtual machine, but then "reset" some aspects so that when I give it to another user, they get the startup experience (in particular, keyboard layout, timezone, region, language, etc).

Is this possible?

If not, should I work around it by creating some script that checks for e.g. a text file/marker (created by said script) and if not found runs various tools (YaST-like?) on startup?

How can a redistributable, partially set up VM be best created?

This question was linked as a duplicate to [Is there a Linux Equivalent to Windows' SysPrep](https://superuser.com/questions/463013/is-there-a-linux-equivalent-to-windows-sysprep) but differs in that:

- None of the answers there describe OpenSUSE or solve this question
- I specifically don't want the install to be "Factory"-like, and require various features to remain as configured (installed software, application-specific configuration files, etc)
- Removing the user is acceptable but not a requirement (although I accept it is likely to be part of the implementation of a solution to my question)
- I don't want to control the distribution of the image later (that question specifies use with "FOG"
- I don't anticipate giving the VM users access to a shared network or directly interacting with their machines (beyond making available a public-facing download with a preloaded VM file)
- SysPrep seems to be specifically related to Windows' licensing - although the outcome might be similar, the goals are perhaps different.

Comment: While you make an OK case for this no being a duplicate, some of your argument stems from not understanding the lingo, I think. Sysprep is a tool that does precisely what you're asking, but for Windows. So the title of the other question does exactly match yours. There isn't an OpenSUSE answer on that other, which is your best argument. Finally, your need to ask one question per post here on this site. You've got at least 2 Qs in the post:pick one and edit the post.